Does Hinduism have female captives from war and can you have sex with them?
Any scripture that says one way or the other?

No. That is forbidden.

After having gained victory in the battle, one should worship gods and
Brahmins. In a battle won by the minister, the gems (acquired by the
minister) should be made over to the king. The wives of a defeated
king would not belong to anyone else (but to that defeated king). The
wives of the defeated king should be protected (by the conquering
king). A king should honour a hostile king defeated in the battle
and treat him as his own son. He should not fight with him again.
[Agni Purana Chapter 236 - 62 to 65]


What about the wives of commoners ?

@অনু I am looking for the verse, will provide when I find it. Meanwhile since wife of king shouldn't be used by others, assume that wives of commoners are also belong to their respective husbands only

@CracklingCyclone the wife of a commoner I believe becomes a dasi and as per arthashastra anyone who forces intercourse on them isn’t permitted, but a dasi wishing to be free from dasahood may commit intercourse with the master. Other than that if a dasi wishes to integrate back into society the courts will handle that and the king should be benevolent.

This is from arthashastra

Thanks that's helpful.
